# Find $\tan(\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(\frac{5}{13}))$

Tags: trigonometry

I wanted to solve it by using this formula: $\tan(\frac{x}{2})=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}.$ I thought it wouldn't work (because there are $\pm$). Then used the right triangle method: $$\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(\frac{5}{13})=\alpha\Rightarrow\frac{5}{26}=\sin\alpha$$ $$a^2+b^2=c^2\Rightarrow a^2+25=676\Rightarrow a=\sqrt{651}\Rightarrow\tan(\frac{5}{\sqrt{651}}).$$ It turned out to be wrong. How to get the right answer?

Comment: Please explain how you concluded $\sin \alpha = \frac{5}{26} $ from the previous equation

Comment: @ofekgillon $$\sin(\frac{1}{2}\arcsin(\frac{5}{13}))=\sin\alpha,$$ $$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{5}{13}=\sin\alpha.$$

Comment: Do you imply that $\sin (\frac{1}{2} \arcsin \frac{5}{13} ) = \sin \arcsin (\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{5}{13})$ ?

Comment: @ofekgillon Yes, exactly. Is it incorrect?

Comment: You should really brush up your algebra, you also made a similar mistake in your last post.

Comment: Look:

$$\frac12 \arcsin 1 = \frac12 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2} = \frac{\pi}{4} $$
$$ \arcsin (\frac12 \cdot 1 ) = \arcsin \frac12 = \frac{\pi}{6} $$
Not the same thing, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta=\arcsin(5/13)$. Problem: find $t=\tan(\theta/2)$. Now
$$\sin\theta=\frac5{13}=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$$
This is a quadratic equation for $t$, etc.

Comment: There is a formula written in my book: $\tan(\arcsin(t))=\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}},$ whish contradicts to $\frac{2t}{1+t^2}.$ So, which is right?

Comment: My formula is correct, but it's not a formula for $\tan(\arcsin(t))$, which equals $t/\sqrt{1-t^2}$.

Comment: Could you write your formula for quadratic tangent in its pure formulaic form, here in comments below, so that I will write that down.

Comment: Let $t=\tan(\theta/2)$. Then $\sin\theta=2t/(1+t^2)$, $\cos\theta=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$ and $\tan\theta=2t/(1-t^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check you first formula. You can use $\arcsin (\frac {2x}{1+x^2})=2\arctan (x) $ and $\arctan (\frac {2x}{1-x^2})=2\arctan (x) $. Both of which can be proved using $x=\tan (t)$. I think you can continue from here.

Comment: **I think you need to check your first formula**. Do you mean that this formula: $\tan(\frac{x}{2})=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}$ works.Why? Because there are 2 signs, which means I get 2 answers, not exactly one.

Comment: No its wrong. Put $x=0$ and you know why its wrong.

Comment: Could you please explain where did you get these 2 formulae: $\arcsin (\frac {2x}{1+x^2})=2\arctan (x)$ and $\arctan (\frac {2x}{1-x^2})=2\arctan (x),$ by comparing and producing a formula from a formula? Because I can't find them.

Comment: Its derived from double angle formulae for $\sin (2x),\tan (2x) $

Answer (score 2):

The formula
$$
\tan\frac{x}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}}
$$
is wrong. You were probably thinking to
$$
\tan\frac{x}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{1+\cos x}}
$$
but there's a better one that doesn't have any sign ambiguity:
$$
\tan\frac{x}{2}=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}
$$
If $x=\arcsin(5/13)$, then $\cos x>0$, so
$$
\cos x=\sqrt{1-\Bigl(\frac{5}{13}\Bigr)^2}=\frac{12}{13}
$$

---

As a side note: from
$$
\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\frac{5}{13}=\alpha
$$
you cannot argue that
$$
\sin\alpha=\frac{5}{26}
$$
You cannot bring $1/2$ inside the arcsine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arcsin(\frac{5}{13})=x$, thus $\sin(x)=\frac{5}{13}$

So, this problem reduced to find value of $\tan(\frac{x}{2})=u$,

According to $\sin(x)=\frac{2u}{u^2+1}$ identity for $u=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$;

$\frac{2u}{u^2+1}=\frac{5}{13}$

$5*(u^2+1)=13*2u$

$5u^2+5=26u$

$5u^2-26u+5=0$

$(u-5)*(5u-1)=0$

Due to $\tan(x)>0$ constraint, $\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ must be equal to $\frac{1}{5}$.

Answer (score 1):

A bisector divides opposite sides in the same ratio as adjacent sides. $ 5= 12/5 +13/5$

So by this property the answer is straightaway $1/5$.

[image: Bisector in 12/13/5 Triangle]

EDIT1:

[image: DoubleAngleTrig]

Comment: I would like to know how you concluded that it is a bisector.

Comment: In the problem you gave it as the ( tan of) argument...of half  the angle of $ \sin^{ -1 }\dfrac{5}{13 }$

Comment: Soon  I shall give a geometric construction for $ \sin 2 \theta$ in terms of  $\tan \theta $ if it interests you. $

Comment: Yes, it does interest me, that will be very helpful :)

Comment: In the above I took $ \tan \theta = 0.4 $

Comment: I tried to fathom the graph as I could, BUT could you explain, please (1) what that spherical shape means, (2) why you have positioned 3 dots (all the dots besides the one at (0;0)) at their current locations, (3) that line which has a length of $x^2$? Because I want to know exactly its association to my problem stated above.

Comment: It helps understand relation of $\sin 2 \theta = PQ/OP \,to \tan \theta =MN/ON $ not only trig symbolically but also geometrically as ratios of triangle sides inside a semi-circle.